# how to save dictionary to cloudkit

Tags: ios, dictionary, cloudkit

I'm trying to create a database for sports games and for instance, in soccer games I would like to save not only how many goals scored, but the time's in which they were scored. The easiest way of course is to use key value pairs but I'm using CloudKit and I don't see a way to save a Dictionary. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I think the solution to this that will give you the most flexability in you app is to create an other recordType. So besides your recordType 'Games' you would also have a recordType 'Goals'. In the 'Goals' recordType you would create a CKReference field that points to the 'Games' that it belongs to. Then you would be able to create a query for the 'Goals' recordType where the reference points to a specific game. You could then calculate the score based on the results of that query.

One other solution that could be easier to maintain is to just convert the dictionary to a string and put the entire dictionary in one text field. You could for instance convert it to a json string with NSJSONSerialization.

Answer (score -3):

You could use [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver) and the field type `Bytes` in CloudKit:

**Convert Dictionary to Data:**

```swift
let dict = [String: Set<String>]()
// convert dictionary to data object
let data: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dict)
// save to CloudKit ...
```

**Convert from Data to Dictionary:**

```swift
// let data: Data = object from CloudKit
let dict: [String: Set<String>] =  NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [String: Set<String>]
```